# Render both Stack and Tab Navigator

Tags: react-native

I'm pretty new at react-native, please bear with me. I have a Stack and Tab navigator that both work well but independently. I, however, need them to work together.

```
const MainTabs = TabNavigator({
  Messages: { screen: MessageScreen },
  Cards: { screen: CardScreen },
  Statements: { screen: StatementScreen },
  Profile: { screen: ProfileScreen },
},
{
    tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: bongzBlue,
    inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
  },
  tabBarComponent: TabBarBottom,
  tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
  animationEnabled: false,
  swipeEnabled: false,
}
);


 export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      // <RootStack />
      <MainTabs />
    );

  }
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific about the problem you are having.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion:

You can nest the StackNavigator in a TabNavigator. So for your specific case, you can make your screens StackNavigators.

For example, your Messages screen can be created like this:

`const MessagesStack = StackNavigator({
 index: { screen: MessageScreen }
 ...
})`

and then you can use it in your TabNavigator and export that as your main component.

`const MainTabs = TabNavigator({
  Messages: { screen: MessageStack },
  ...
},`

Hope this helps.